# f:setPropertyActionListener not calling method

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need some help. I'm having trouble with using `f:setPropertyActionListener` on JSF. The problem is that the JSF is not setting any value on the target method.

Part of the xhtml code is the following:

```
<h:form>
    <fieldset style="width:100; margin-left: 350px; margin-top: 250px; position:absolute; border-style: none">
        <p:dataGrid var="prod" value="#{productoController.arrProductosRelevantes}" 
                    columns="5" rows="10" paginator="true">

            <p:panel style="text-align:center">  
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%" columnClasses="colStyle1" rowClasses="rowStyle1" >  
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{prod.imagenUrl}" style="width:100px; height:100px"/>   
                    <h:outputText value="#{prod.marca}" style="width:40px"/>  
                    <p:commandLink value="Ver" action="#{productoController.visualizarProducto()}">  
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{prod}"   
                                                     target="#{productoController.productoSeleccionado()}" />  
                    </p:commandLink>
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:panel>  
        </p:dataGrid>  
    </fieldset>
</h:form>
```

The backing bean is the following (the most relevant):

```
public Producto getProductoSeleccionado() {
    return productoSeleccionado;
}

public void setProductoSeleccionado(Producto productoSeleccionado) {
    if (productoSeleccionado != null) {
        this.productoSeleccionado = productoSeleccionado;
        arrComentarios = null;
        arrProductosComplementarios = null;
        arrProductosSuplementarios = null;
    }
}

public String visualizarProducto() {
    if (arrComentarios == null) {
        obtenerComentarios();
    }
    if (arrProductosComplementarios == null) {
        obtenerArrProductosComplementarios();
    }
    if (arrProductosSuplementarios == null) {
        obtenerArrProductosSuplementarios();
    }
    return "visualizarProducto.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}


public ArrayList<Producto> getArrProductosRelevantes() {
    return arrProductosRelevantes;
}

public void obtenerArrProductosRelevantes() {
    clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO();
    productoDAO = new ProductoDAO();
    cliente = clienteDAO.getClientePorId(Sesion.IDCLIENTE);
    arrProductosRelevantes = productoDAO.obtenerProductoRelevantesPorCliente(cliente);
}
```

By the way, I'm using @SessionScoped.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The *target* attribute of `f:setPropertyActionListener` is supposed to be a property, not a method. That means, if you set `target="#{productoController.productoSeleccionado}"` it will call the `setProductoSeleccionado(Producto prod)` method in the `productoController` bean, passing as argument the value you set for the *value* attribute.

You are referring to a method `productoSeleccionado()` that may well not even exist in your code. So, just lose the parenthesis and you should be fine:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{prod}"
               target="#{productoController.productoSeleccionado}" />
```

Comment: Actually there's a method called setProductoSeleccionado() as I've shown previously in the backbean code and it's not setting the product even if took off the parentheses

Comment: Also, I have used that method through other JSF page, but in this one it's just not working

Comment: I know the setter is there, but you were not referring to it, you were referring to a `productoSeleccionado()` method. Now, when you took off the parenthesis, then the setter was really being referenced, and why it isn't working now it may be another thing. What scope is your bean?

Comment: Then you should be set. Can you update the code in the question as the code you are using right now?

Comment: Instead of using a datagrid for my particular purpose I changed it to a datatable and it's working fine. Thank you for your time